# Button for DateTime Picker 

Tags: c#, button, datetimepicker

I am creating a touchscreen application and I am using two datapickers, but the button of the DateTimePicker is too small, so I decided to overlay a button to that of datatimepicker, but what is the code used to display the month view?

Answer (score 1):

try this, button1 is your big button...

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const uint WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessage(dateTimePicker1.Handle, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Down, 0);
}
```

Comment: but, I don't know where I must paste this code... "private void button1_Click" ok in my Form1.cs, but the other code??? thanks

Comment: Copy as it is and ad an event for button click

Comment: add missing reference, learn how to use the help and read carefully visual studio errors...

Comment: I'm a beginner, do not have the reference to add. Visual studio says it is impossible to find the type or namespace name DllImport; probably missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Comment: msdn help tells you in which assembly DllImport is defined